# Relation between components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two stateful components:Grid and Item.Item is rendering by Grid and have props which reference to method (handler) defined in Grid `<Item example={this.props.inGridHandler} />`
Ok. But what if I have third stateful component let's name it Handy and I want that inGridHandler is defined not in Grid component as before but in Handy. How to achieve this with preserving all this structure ?

```
class Grid extends Component{

ingridHandler=()=>{
console.log('I want to be  defined in Handy Component, not here');
}

Render(){
Return(
`<Item example={this.inGridHandler} />`
);

}
};
export default Grid;




class Handy extends Component{

inGridHandlerWantToBeDefinedHere=()=>{
console.log("I want to be defined here and pass to Grid component as props of Item component which is rendered there'
}

render(){

return(

)
}


}
```

Comment: Hello. As its current shape, your question does not mean much for the ones who want to help you. Please share some code with us. It is better if it would be a working example. If you don't provide those possibly your question will be voted for closing.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. How is `Handy` going to look like. Is `Grid` always going to render `Item`. From what you are saying `Item` should be reusable in both `Grid` and `Handy`. Thats the only thing i see.

Comment: Let me try to understand you. You want to define `ingridHandler` handler in the `Handy` component and pass this to the `Grid` component, right? If this is what you want you should render `Grid` in the `Handy` component.

Comment: @devserkan Not exactly. I want to define ingridHandler handler in Handy component and use it in Item component BUT Item Component must be rendered inside Grid Component. All my problem comes with that I want to use handler from another Component to this in which my Item is rendered.

Comment: Again, you can pass it to `Item` from `Grid`. `Handy` renders `Grid` and pass the handler, `Grid` renders `Item` and pass the handler as `handler={this.props.ingridHandler}`. I don't know what is the point of this logic but if you don't want to pass the props all the way down like here, you can change your logic maybe. Using a container component, using context API or maybe using render props. If you are learning React and new to this, just try to think a little bit simple at first.

Comment: @devserkan thank you very much. I'm new to React and I wanted create main component in which I will be render all other components without much logic but it turned out one of them need to use handler which comes from another component, I didn't want to write it in that "grid" component.

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, sometimes we need to pass some props a few levels deep. This is a common issue in React and there are some good approaches for this. As you study and look at other people's code, tutorials you can see those. But first, just digest the basics. Oh, by the way, try to use a linter :) Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you want if I understand you right. This is a very simple process. You are just passing the props all the way down. But, as I try to explain in my comments in the future you should think better approaches if you don't want to pass the props like this.

```js
class Handy extends React.Component {
  inGridHandler = () => {
    console.log("ingridhandler");
  };

  render() {
    return <Grid inGridHandler={this.inGridHandler} />;
  }
}

class Grid extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Item inGridHandler={this.props.inGridHandler} />;
  }
}

const Item = props => (
  <button onClick={props.inGridHandler}>Click me and look the console.</button>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Handy />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```